# How to offset bitmap, drawn on a canvas?

Tags: java, android

Here's my code that draws a BitmapMesh, as well as a circle on canvas.

```
canvas.drawBitmapMesh(GirlBitmap, WIDTH, HEIGHT, matrixVertsMoved, 0,  null, 0, null); // need to offset this by "addOffset"

canvas.drawCircle(pointX+addOffset, pointY, bubbleSize, p3);
```

Both of which have to be offset by x by **addOffset**. It wors fine with the circle, but I can't figure out how to make the bitmap offset?

Any ideas? Maybe I should draw it on a separate canvas and then draw it on the old one, with an offset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can't you just `translate` the `Canvas` by `(addOffset, 0)`? Like this:

```
final int saveCount = canvas.save();
try {
    canvas.translate(addOffset, 0);

    canvas.drawBitmapMesh(GirlBitmap, WIDTH, HEIGHT, matrixVertsMoved, 0,  null, 0, null); 
    canvas.drawCircle(pointX, pointY, bubbleSize, p3);
} finally {
    canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
}
```